# Subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The exact question is:

> Is it possible that a ring with unity may simultaneously contain subrings isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$, where $n \ne m$?

The answer says it's possible and says $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ has a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and one isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$. I'm just trying to understand the problem better, but I can't see which two subrings are isomorphic. Could someone explain this solution to me? Thank you.

Comment: HINT: $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3 \cong  \Bbb Z_6$.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in the category of rings, yes, as shown in another answer.

But if you are working in the category of *rings with unity*, that is, if you insist on **subrings having the same unity as  the ring in which they are contained**, then you have a problem.

In fact, in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ you have $n \cdot 1 = 0$ (where $1$ is the unity, and $n \cdot 1$ denotes the $n$-th multiple of $1$), and $k \cdot 1 \ne 0$ for $0 < k < n$. In $\mathbb{Z}_m$ you have $m \cdot 1 = 0$, and $k \cdot 1 \ne 0$ for $0 < k < m$.

If $m < n$ or $n < m$ we obtain  a contradiction. So $m = n$.

Comment: So are you saying it isn't possible? This problem is from Fraleigh Abstract Algebra by the way, section 27 #25, if you need additional reference. The solutions seem to say it is possible... now I'm getting confused.

Comment: ***It depends very much on the exact definitions.*** Do you insist on subrings to have the same identity as the ring? Then my argument applies. You allow subrings to have a different identity? Then the argument in the other answer applies.

Comment: What is the contradiction? The two unities are diferent $1_{\mathbb{Z}_n} \neq 1_{\mathbb{Z}_m}$ and $1_{\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m}=(1_{\mathbb{Z}_n},1_{\mathbb{Z}_m})$ is different than the two previous ones. Still there is an isomorphism between $R = \{(n,1_{\mathbb{Z}_m}); n \in \mathbb{Z}_n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Also, both $1_{\mathbb{Z}_n}$ and $1_{\mathbb{Z}_m}$ are contained in $R$.

Answer (score 3):

The two are $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ with the most natural isomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}_2\times \{0\}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2,$$
and analogously for the other subring.

Comment: The problem is that these aren't sub(rings with unity). They are sub[rngs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)), they both have a unit, but the unit doesn't correspond to the unit of the full ring.

Comment: Sure. That's why in that case the other answer applies.